# How do I fix URL is not supported on Antd

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Whenever I try to run my react js project with antd, I receive these kinds of errors

```js
WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/config-provider/style/index.less' URL is not supported

WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/icon/style/index.less' URL is not supported

WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/locale-provider/style/index.less' URL is not supported

WARNING in ./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[1]!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[1].rules[1].oneOf[5].use[2]!./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/antd/dist/antd.css)
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map: 'webpack://antd/./components/time-picker/style/index.less' URL is not supported
```

Answer (score 3):

This changed in antd v5.x

To fix, replace `import 'antd/dist/antd.css'` from your `App.css` file with:

```
import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of {import 'antd/dist/antd.css'} Import this command
{import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css'}

> > Not to copy with curly braces/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Simply instead of import 'antd/dist/antd.css' Import below command in your app.js file

> import 'antd/dist/antd.min.css'